# Quick Look at Objects in Rhino Shell (PHP var_dump equivalent?)

Tags: javascript, rhino

Is there a better way of debugging in Rhino than typing this everytime? :

```
for (prop in obj) { print("obj[" + prop + "] = " + obj[prop]); };
```

Update: To be clear, my question is whether there are any existing standard practices/modules/tricks on this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`obj.toSource()` will do for basic inspection.

Answer (score 1):

For

```
obj.toSource()
```

there seems to be a strange case where it does not show, ex:

```
var v = [];
v['love'] = 'amore';    
print(v.toSource());
```

while your original code (you can wrap it int a dump() works.